# convert array to hash and initialize to a value

Tags: ruby

what is the best way to convert an array of

```
arr = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five"]
```

to hash of

```
{"one"=>0, "two"=>0, "three"=>0, "four"=>0, "five"=>0}
```

Iam planning to fillup the '0' with my own values later, I just need the technique now.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
arr.product([0]).to_h
```

or for versions < 2.0

```
Hash[arr.product([0])]
```

Answer (score 5):

I don't know if it's the *best* way:

```
Hash[arr.map{ |el| [el, 0] }]
```

Answer (score 3):

I would do this:

```
arr.inject({}) { |hash, key| hash.update(key => 0) }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Hash[ *arr.collect { |v| [ v, 0 ] }.flatten ]
```

Comment: per some very rough benchmarks, of those posted, this one seems to be the fastest for single large arrays, but lags behind when dealing with large numbers of small arrays.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do

```
arr.each_with_object({}) {|v, h| h[v] = 1}
```

where:

- `v` is the value of each element in the array,
- `h` represents the hash object